# My page isn't showing up correctly on IE?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I've removed all in-line and unified all widths and heights using px however it is still not showing correctly on IE.

```
   .textbox {
    background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    width:172px; 
    height:220px; 
    border:solid; 
    border-width:1px; 
    border-color:#CCC;

    .gap    {
    padding:5px;
    }

    .text {
    color:#FFF;
    margin-top:20px;
    margin-left:45px;
    margin-bottom:0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:40px;
}

<td class="tdstyle2">
                    <div class="textbox">
                        <img alt="2nd Day Of Christmas" src="/netalogue/2nd-day-christmas-blurry.jpg">
                        <div class="gap">
                            <p class="text">2nd</p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </td>
```

Please note you will not be able to see images as the URLs are changed by the web platform https://jsfiddle.net/5s8f01r5/1/

Comment: Try removing the `px` from `<td>`'s height?

Comment: Don't mix inline and external CSS. Throw away `height`/`width` attributes - use css. Also provide SO Snippet or JSFiddle

Answer (score 0):

You could clearn your code with something like this:

```
.textbox {
background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
width:172px; 
height:220px; 
border:solid; 
border-width:1px; 
border-color:#CCC;
}

.text {
color:#FFF;
margin-top:20px;
margin-left:45px;
margin-bottom:0px;
font-weight:bold;
font-size:40px;
}
.general {
height: 222px;
width: 182px;
}
.padding-div {
padding: 5px;
}
.size-img{
width:172px;
height: 126px;
}

<div class="general">
     <div class="textbox">
          <img alt="2nd Day Of Christmas" src="/netalogue/2nd-day-christmas-blurry.jpg" class="size-img">
               <div class="padding-div"><p class="text">2nd</p></div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, I was actually doing this exact thing. However the problem is still there

Comment: Try to remove que / before the img URL

Comment: the / is automated by our web platform. It doesn't effect the way that the image is displayed. The real URL is http://www.londongraphics.co.uk/netalogue/1st-day-christmas-clear.jpg

Comment: Have you tried the absolute image address? Because here is working

Comment: We can't, the web platform just strips it out.

Comment: Try this src="netalogue/2nd-day-christmas-blurry.jpg" instead src="/netalogue/2nd-day-christmas-blurry.jpg" for test

Comment: I have tested this and nothing happens, the problem is still there.